# 5 card flush on table

Tags: flush

There was a 5 card flush on the table

5s 6s 10s Js Qs

my buddy has a 5d and 6c hand 
I had 2s and Ac

Is it a split pot because we both have flush, or should the pot be mine because I have the same suit as the flush? but that same suit in my hand is a 2, so does it make a difference? Or does it depend on who has the highest card, for example the Ace card in my hand?

He also insisted that the pot should be his because he has a two pair on top of that flush and said that the winner is decided by the person with the most combinations for example he had flush and two pair and I had only flush but I know that's not the case

Answer (score 0):

The rule is very very simple.

Construct the best 5 card hand with the 7 cards available to you (5 community and 2 hole cards), no exceptions.

Your best 5 cards hand:

5s 6s 10s Js Qs

His best 5 cards hand:

5s 6s 10s Js Qs

It's a split pot. Why would the Ace or the 2 pairs even matter? Even if you could choose to play your hand as Ace-high, you would just be beaten by his flush; similarly if he could choose to play his hand as 2 pairs, he would just be beaten by your flush.

... Also, you can't choose what hands to play, best 5 cards period. This will be a split pot.

Comment: You know you have authority to VTC?

Comment: Thanks for the answer, fairly new player here not very familiar with the best 5 card rule until now.